# Json request parameter standard

Tags: json, api, rest, request, standards

I am working on a project which uses partially practices RESTful API (as of now) and there is a concern that is plaguing the team. Our main question is that is it a bad practice for front end to return information that can be queried by the backend. There is a trade-off between security and performance here.

Scenario :

Frontend has let's say, latitude and longitude of a location which backend will use for some logical processing. The latitude and longitude can be queried by the backend, given the location's ID. If frontend passes the the lat/long in the request, backend would need to do one less database query. There is a risk of request hijacking but if non-transactional data are passed in from the front end, it would less likely to bog down the performance in the long run. Especially when everything is scaled upwards.

Questions :

While it is, needless to say, less secure if the parameter is passed in from the front end, is there a standard for how these scenarios should be handled? Are there any exceptions or examples of best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Does the server need a `Location` or a `Latitude, Longitude` pair to do its "logical processing"? If I punch in two random valid numbers for long, lat, does the server do something useful or useless? That should clearly indicate what the client needs to pass up.

If you have performance concerns about DB lookups, solve that problem (with a cache, or indexing, or ...). Don't mess up your API layer to fix something two layers down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will take that into consideration when designing API